# Which debconf preseed option to install GRUB automatically to MBR?

Tags: grub2, preseed, debconf

### NOTE: I'm using preseed here , this step should be done automatically from preseed config

This is the final step before finishing installation , install grub to MBR:

[image]

I'm not sure which debconf option should use here , to bypass this screen ; after installation , i tried to get all possible used debconf strings , and nothing contains `mbr`

Comment: You might want to include that you are want to preseed this option more prominently in the question.  I missed the tag reading through it the first time and it looks like virpara did the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no other OS detected:

`d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true`

If other OS detected:

`d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true`

Answer (score 5):

It is advised to install GRUB bootloader to MBR (this will replace current bootloader from MBR) after installation. Because MBR tells GRUB to load when the system is booted.

I found this how to make it react for MBR

```
# This is fairly safe to set, it makes grub install automatically to the MBR
# if no other operating system is detected on the machine.
d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean true

# This one makes grub-installer install to the MBR if it also finds some other
# OS, which is less safe as it might not be able to boot that other OS.
d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean true
```

and this if you don't want to install in MBR

```
# Alternatively, if you want to install to a location other than the mbr,
# uncomment and edit these lines:
#d-i grub-installer/only_debian boolean false
#d-i grub-installer/with_other_os boolean false
#d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string (hd0,0)
# To install grub to multiple disks:
#d-i grub-installer/bootdev  string (hd0,0) (hd1,0) (hd2,0)
```

these configurations are taken from Debian Lenny's preseed file [here](http://www.debian.org/releases/lenny/example-preseed.txt)

[this one is helpful for other examples](http://www.instalinux.com/)

Comment: @izx but in first line it says `(for lenny)`

Comment: sorry, wrong link: [this is](http://www.debian.org/releases/squeeze/example-preseed.txt) the preseed example for Debian Squeeze (6.0)